# Enterキーでコメントを送信することができない / I can't press enter to send a comment

Tags: バグ, 仕様

When I type a comment and press enter, it doesn't send - to send the comment I have to click the button.

Why is this?

Google Chrome 41.0.2272.101 and Firefox 36.0.4

---

コメントを入力したあとEnterを押しても送信されず、「コメントの追加」ボタンを押す必要があります。

これは何故でしょう？

Comment: @Unarist Thanks! 感謝

Answer (score 4, accepted):

日本語では入力すると「変換」しながら<kbd>Enter</kbd>を押します。<kbd>Enter</kbd>でコメントを投稿すると、変換途中に投稿してしまうケースが多いため、当サイトと「Japanese Language and Usage」では<kbd>Enter</kbd>を押すと投稿しないようにしています。

---

When you type in Japanese you use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm which characters with that reading you want to select. If you can submit comments with <kbd>Enter</kbd> then a lot of the time you end up submitting a comment accidentally while inputting text which is frustrating. So on this site and on Japanese Language & Usage, we disabled submission of comments on <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!